# Select values from 2 different tables and print values in a row with the same ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this database

TABLE "ADS"

```
ID   |   Visible
-----------------
15   |      1
16   |      1
17   |      1
```

TABLE "IMAGES_ADS"

```
ID    |    NAME    |   ID_ADS
------------------------------
100   |  xlasd.jpg |    15
101   |  dadsa.jpg |    15
102   |  dsfsf.jpg |    16
103   |  ghdfd.jpg |    17
104   |  jkyhg.jpg |    17
105   |  rerem.jpg |    17
```

Now I want create a php page that get values from this 2 tables and print a list of ADS by id with a row of the images name relate to the ADS ID separated by a comma.

I wrote this code

```
<?php
//ENTER YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION INFO BELOW:
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "xxxxxx";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
    echo 'CONNECT TO DB';
}

$sql = "SELECT ADS.ID, IMAGES_ADS.NAME FROM ADS INNER JOIN IMAGES_ADS ON ADS.ID=IMAGES_ADS.ID_ADS WHERE ADS.Visible=1 ORDER BY ID ASC";
$results = $conn->query($sql);

echo '<table>';

if($results->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$row["ID"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["NAME"].'</td>
              </tr>';
    }
} else {
    echo '0 rows';
}
echo '</table>';

$conn->close();
?>
```

But with this code I get this result:

```
15  xlasd.jpg
15  dadsa.jpg
16  dsfsf.jpg
17  ghdfd.jpg
17  jkyhg.jpg
17  rerem.jpg
```

But I need this kind of result:

```
15  xlasd.jpg, dadsa.jpg
16  dsfsf.jpg
17  ghdfd.jpg, jkyhg.jpg, rerem.jpg
```

How can I have this result?

Thanks to @Vipin Jain I write the solution below:

```
<?php
//ENTER YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION INFO BELOW:
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "xxxxxx";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
    echo 'CONNECT TO DB';
}

$sql = "SELECT ADS.ID, GROUP_CONCAT(IMAGES_ADS.NAME SEPARATOR', ') as b
        FROM ADS INNER JOIN IMAGES_ADS
        ON ADS.ID=IMAGES_ADS.ID_ADS
        WHERE ADS.Visible=1
        ORDER BY ID ASC";

$results = $conn->query($sql);

echo '<table>';

if($results->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$row["ID"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["b"].'</td>
              </tr>';
    }
} else {
    echo '0 rows';
}
echo '</table>';

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Looks at using `group_concat`...

Comment: Is it ok if the good array structure is achieved with PHP ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

```
SELECT ADS.ID, GROUP_CONCAT(IMAGES_ADS.NAME)
FROM ADS 
INNER JOIN IMAGES_ADS 
ON ADS.ID=IMAGES_ADS.ID_ADS 
WHERE ADS.Visible=1 
GROUP BY ID 
ORDER BY ID ASC;
```

Comment: You should also group by `ADS.ID`, don't you?

Comment: ya i added i forget to add it at that time

Comment: Thank you so much.
I only did this change
 

    "SELECT ADS.ID, GROUP_CONCAT(IMAGES_ADS.NAME SEPARATOR ', ') as b
      FROM ADS
      INNER JOIN IMAGES_ADS
      ON ADS.ID=IMAGES_ADS.ID_ADS
      WHERE ADS.Visible=1
      GROUP BY ADS.ID
      ORDER BY ID ASC";
for call the "b" alias in the php code.

Answer (score 1):

You can get by below query-

```
SELECT a.ID, GROUP_CONCAT(b.NAME)
FROM ADS as a
INNER JOIN IMAGES_ADS as b
ON a.ID=b.ID_ADS 
WHERE ADS.Visible=1 
Group by a.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = [];    
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    if (empty($res[$row["ID"]])) {
        $res[$row["ID"]] = [$row];
    } else {
        $res[$row["ID"]][] = $row;
    }
}
```

you'll get arrays of rows grouped by ID